# dropzone - var this not working (xhr formdata) inside another function's callback the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, dropzone.js

I have a register form with dropzone and I'd like to validate it (the fields) using a plugin. I call this plugin inside the dropzone init and inside its function's callback I process the dropzone queue and attach the form data.

The problem is that, the first time I click the `<a id="click">Send</a>` button, nothing happens: it just enters the callback of the function and does nothing (`myDropzone` not working), only the `console.log()` (that I put for debugging).

This is the plugin I'm using:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.formly = function(callback) {
        $('a#click').on('click', function() {
            if (callback) {

                var clientInfo = form.find(':input').serializeArray();

                clientInfo.splice(-1, 1);
                clientInfo.splice(-1, 1);

                // Password hash function
                var p = $('#reg_pwd').val(),
                    c = $('#confirm_pwd').val(),
                    shaObj = new jsSHA('SHA-512', 'TEXT');

                shaObj.update(p);
                var p_hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX"),
                    shaObj = new jsSHA('SHA-512', 'TEXT');

                shaObj.update(c);
                var c_hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");

                callback(clientInfo, p_hash, c_hash);
            }
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

And this is the dropzone init:

```
init: function() {
    var myDropzone = this;

    $('#register').formly(function(clientInfo, p_hash, c_hash) {
console.log(myDropzone);
        myDropzone.processQueue();

        myDropzone.on('sending', function(data, xhr, formData) {
            formData.append('client_info', JSON.stringify(clientInfo)),
            formData.append('particular', 0),
            formData.append('reg_pwd', p_hash),
            formData.append('confirm_pwd', c_hash)
        });

    });

    myDropzone.on('success', function(file, response) {
        myDropzone.removeFile(file);
        console.log( 'Error: ' + response );
    });
}
```

I can see the object logged in the console.

It's like nothing (no xhr request) is sent to the server when I first click the button.

The second time I click "Send" it does work (it sends the xhr request) and I get a server response (`myDropzone.on('success'`).

Why does it work after the first time? What Am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: My guess is that the first time doesn't work, because you create the event listener that triggers your validation of  the form inside a function that is only called on sending, and this occurs later than the button is pressed. So the first time you click there is no event listener, this is created on this first click, and then works on the subsequent clicks.

Comment: I don't understand, the only code inside the `on.('sending')` is the form data I'm trying to attach to the images (the four lines starting by `formData.append`. Not that I'm a javascript expert, though. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, now I understand, dropzone only listens what's inside the init, not the callback of the function, so that's why, the first time the `on.('sending')` is inside the callback and dropzone doesn't know, but the second time it "kinda knows"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a vague idea of why the code is acting like that, but I lack the necessary knowledge (theory) to properly explain it.

Anyways, I (think) found a proper way of doing it, I hope it's up to the standards of good techniques. I'm now using a function to populate a scoped object in the dropzone init so that `.on('sending')` (that should be outside the plugin callback) can access the form data:

```
init: function() {

    var myDropzone = this,
        client = {};

    function getClientData(clientInfo, p_hash, c_hash) {
        client.clientInfo   = clientInfo;
        client.p_hash       = p_hash;
        client.c_hash       = c_hash;
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    };

    $('#register').formly(function(clientInfo, p_hash, c_hash) {

        getClientData(clientInfo, p_hash, c_hash);

    });

    myDropzone.on('sending', function(data, xhr, formData) {
        formData.append('client_info', JSON.stringify(client.clientInfo)),
        formData.append('particular', 0),
        formData.append('reg_pwd', client.p_hash),
        formData.append('confirm_pwd', client.c_hash)
    });

    myDropzone.on('success', function(file, response) {
        myDropzone.removeFile(file);
        console.log( 'Error: ' + response );
    })

}
```

I'll gladly accept another answer that explains the behavior of the original code and have a better approach (if any).